# How do I compare the variabilities between groups with extremely different ranges?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, online-resources

It's hard to fit it all in the title but my problem is basically finding a measure of variability or spread that I could use to compare groups where some have really high values while others have really low values. I can't use S.D. and variance because the ones with bigger values would obviously have bigger variances and S.D.. I was thinking of measuring skewdness but I can't think of a way to justify it with a research paper.

Comment: Can you give some examples of sets of data that you think might have similar "variability" despite one having bigger values and the other smaller values?  Note that the sets $\{1,3,4\}$ and $\{101,103,104\}$ have the same variances and standard deviations, while $\{100,300,400\}$ has more.